# Magento 2 : Filter Product Grid Using Category In Admin

Tags: category, magento-2.1, grid, filter

Is there any way to filter products grid collection in the admin > Product > Catalog grid by category Magento 2.1+?

I would like to filter products that are within a filtered category.

There seems to be a few examples of how to add Category column to the Grid however, I have tried 3 separate examples, and none of them seem to work.

Comment: take into consider that Product can be assign to more thn one category

Comment: I also have a similar problem. Could you help me to solve, please? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173195/magento-2-1-create-a-filter-in-the-product-grid-by-new-attribute

Comment: Buy Amasty's Grid editor, it adds all sorts of sort functions including categories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if this is an old thread there is still no free solution... So I've created a free extension that adds the feature of category filter in the admin product grid.

https://github.com/utklasad/magento2-admin-product-grid-category-filter

Cheers!

Comment: Hi i have installed your extension, but when i click on the catalog in admin panel i'm getting this error {"0":"Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Utklasad\\AdminProductGridCategoryFilter\\Model\\Category\\CategoryList::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\CollectionFactory, instance of Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager given, called in \/var\/www\/html\/work\/hoodmart\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php . Can you help me please.

Comment: I have fixed it. app/code/Utklasad/AdminProductGridCategoryFilter/Model/Category/Categorylist.php. in this file change the class name from CategoryList to Categorylist

Comment: Ah, sorry for the typo there... I will fix it in the repo. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using magento 2.3, there is not showing in admin. i have done all steps of installations. but now showing in admin.

Comment: It's working fine in Magento 2.3.2 for me. The position of the filter might have changed compared to the screenshot in the readme. Please take a double look and open a issue at GitHub if you still are experiencing problems.

Comment: Man why is this not a core feature. Cheers!

Comment: it looks like the "open source community" has give in the edge to it's enterprise counterpart

Comment: Please can someone from the Magento team explain why this is not a core feature?? You can filter by custom attributes but not built in categories..? MADNESS!!