# Magento 2.1 Create a filter in the product grid by new attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, products, filter

I used Magento 2.1 and want to add new filter in the product grid. But when I added my module the website loading forever.
Please help me to solve the problem. I have searched on the internet, but I didn't see any similar problem.
Bellow my code:

> etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="addFieldStrategies" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="configurable_options" xsi:type="object">Training\Unit6\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddConfigurableOptionsToCollection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

> Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Options.php

```
namespace Training\Unit6\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Options implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    protected $options;
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $this->options = [
            [
                'label' => ' ',
                'value' => 0
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'One',
                'value' => 1
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Two',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Three',
                'value' => 3
            ],
        ];
        return $this->options;
    }
}
```

> Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddConfigurableOptionsToCollection.php

```
namespace Training\Unit6\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute\Collection as ConfigurableCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;

class AddConfigurableOptionsToCollection implements AddFilterToCollectionInterface {

    protected $configurableOptions = null;

    public function __construct(ConfigurableCollection $collection) {
        $this->configurableOptions = $collection;
    }

    public function addFilter(Collection $collection, $field, $condition = null) {
        if (isset($condition['eq']) && ($numberOfOptions = $condition['eq'])) {

            $select = $this->configurableOptions->getSelect()
                ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
                ->columns(array('product_id', 'COUNT(*) as cnt'))
                ->group('product_id');

            $res = $this->configurableOptions->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);

            $ids = array();
            foreach ($res as $opt) {
                if ($opt['cnt'] == $numberOfOptions) {
                    $ids[] = $opt['product_id'];
                }
            }
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $ids));
        }
    }

}
```

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<container name="listing_top">
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <filterSelect name="configurable_options">
            <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Training\Unit6\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Options</argument>
            </argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName }</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">configurable_options</item>
                    <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select...</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Configurable options</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSelect>
    </filters>
</container>
```

Here is my module https://www.dropbox.com/s/lt6riovjaju4se9/unit6.zip?dl=0

Comment: No need to add any custom code. Only setting admin side in attribute 

Add to Column Options : Yes & Use in Filter Options : Yes under Advanced Attribute Properties

Answer (score 5):

No need to add any custom code. In magento2.x available default setting under the attribute

Go admin side `Stores -> Attributes -> Product` and open your created attribute

After click `Advanced Attribute Properties` tab under the **Properties** tab and set **Yes** below two fields

1. Use in Filter Options: Yes (Select "Yes" to add this attribute to the list of filter options in the product grid.)
2. Add to Column Options: Yes (Select "Yes" to add this attribute to the list of column options in the product grid.
   )

After saving attribute and check product grid.

Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Abdul. I know I can show that on the config product attribute. But I have many environments (dev, staging, live). I can't remember all changes when I deploy, I need change by code, but your comment is great.

Comment: Sorry I can't vote your comment because my account don't enough reputation.

Answer (score 4):

> In the view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

Change `<container name="listing_top">` to `<listingToolbar name="listing_top">` it's worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. I follow by https://github.com/DRAJI/Categoryfilter. It's worked. But I don't know how to keep the filter field and remove that field in product grid?
[image]

Here is my code:

> etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider" type="Training\Unit6\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddProductSeriesOptionsToCollection"/>
</config>
```

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    </listingToolbar>
        <column name="product_series" class="Training\Unit6\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ProductSeries">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product series</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ProductSeries.php

```
namespace Training\Unit6\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
/**
 * Class Price
 */
class ProductSeries extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    protected $_productloader;
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    }
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        //$fieldName = $this->getData('name');
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

> Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddProductSeriesOptionsToCollection.php

```
namespace Training\Unit6\Ui\DataProvider\Product;
class AddProductSeriesOptionsToCollection extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider
{
    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
    {
        if($filter->getField()=='unit6'){
            $this->getCollection()->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $filter->getValue()));
        }
        elseif (isset($this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()])) {
            $this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()]
                ->addFilter(
                    $this->getCollection(),
                    $filter->getField(),
                    [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]
                );
        } else {
            parent::addFilter($filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

namespace Training\Unit6\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
/**

- Class Price
  */
  class ProductSeries extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
  {
  protected $_productloader;
  public function __construct(
  ContextInterface $context,
  UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
  array $components = [],
  array $data = []
  ) {
  parent::__construct($context,$uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
  $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
  }
  /**

  - Prepare Data Source
  - 
  - @param array $dataSource
  - @return array
    */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
    //$fieldName = $this->getData('name');
    return $dataSource;
    }
    }
    Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddProductSeriesOptionsToCollection.php

namespace Training\Unit6\Ui\DataProvider\Product;
class AddProductSeriesOptionsToCollection extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider
{
public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
{
if($filter->getField()=='unit6'){
$this->getCollection()->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $filter->getValue()));
}
elseif (isset($this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()])) {
$this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()]
->addFilter(
$this->getCollection(),
$filter->getField(),
[$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]
);
} else {
parent::addFilter($filter);
}
}
}
Share
Improve this answer
Follow
edited May 8, 2017 at 8:25
answered May 8, 2017 at 8:14
Trang Lee's user avatar
Trang Lee
13411 gold badge11 silver badge1010 bronze badges
Add a comment
Your Answer